# Extra line in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, objectlistview

I am using the  [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), and I use the following code to add rows:

```
lvServiceClassInfo.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
            List<CPerson> list = new List<CPerson>();
            list.Add(new CPerson() { name = "a", wsdl = "abc" });
            list.Add(new CPerson() { name = "b", wsdl = "abc" });
            list.Add(new CPerson() { name = "c", wsdl = "abc" });
            lvServiceClassInfo.AddObjects(list);
```

But I have extra line between each row(the line with "a", with a horizontal bar across), how to get rid of it?
[image]

Comment: looks like a show/hide ,expander control to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the ObjectListView.  They look like the grouping lines.  To get rid if them make sure that the ShowGroups property is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Codelgnoto, there is a property called ShowGroups for the list view to hide the bar :)